# Custom VRP datasets using graph hopper

Tags: java, optimization, optaplanner, graphhopper

I am looking for a java code or library to generate the custom VRP datasets with road distances using graph hopper. Could you please share the details.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

See my repo that needs to be cleaned up and some code added in optaplanner-webexamples:
  https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator

Comment: I am getting issues in downloading the maven dependencies specified in the pom.xml in the project vrp-dataset-generator. Having maven enforcer issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to run the project. Thank you